# How can I make jquery wait for one function to finish before executing another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function test(){
var distance=null;
       first();
       second();
       third();
alert(distance);//it shows null always because it take 2 second to complete.

}
 function first(tolat, tolon, fromlat,fromlon){

// calulating road distance between two points on the map using any other distance caluculating apis. 

distance=dis;  // update the value of distance but it takes 2 second to complete.

}
 function second(){}
 function third(){}
```

i have this type of situation in my code, now many time function three is called before first and second complete execution and distance value is not updated.

Comment: Check jQuery when() function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Maybe you could call one function from another?

Comment: the best approach depends entirely on what "any other distance caluculating api" is doing.

Comment: I've removed the J tag from this question as this question has nothing to with the J language. Please be more careful when tagging your questions in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Take advantage of jquery queueing.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095263/how-do-i-chain-or-queue-custom-functions-using-jquery

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make use of callbacks:

```
function first(tolat, tolon, fromlat, fromlon, callback) {
     if (typeof(callback) == 'function') {
        callback(distance);
     }
}

function second() { }
function third() { }

first("vartolat", "vartolon", "varfromlat", "varfromlon", function(distance) {
    alert(distance);
    second();
    third();
});
```

Comment: I like this one, had no clue how to use callbacks. Going to research into this, thank you.

Comment: These functions (like yours) are called 'asynchronous functions'. Callbacks prevent other functions from executing before the ansynchronous ones are completed (when used properly). You're welcome.