# how do I turn my jQuery function/extension to animation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, prototype-programming

as you all know, in jQuery you can do an animation chain as easy as: `$('obj').fadeIn().fadeOut();`

now I've made an extension, and want to be able to add it to animations of jQuery and be able to chain-animate: `$('obj').fadeIn().myFunction().fadeOut();`

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TwLLZ/

Comment: Your fiddle is already working, what is your question?

Comment: i just did it in your fiddle and it worked.

Comment: what do you mean?!! show me!

Comment: sounds like exact duplicate of [How do I chain or queue custom functions using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095263/how-do-i-chain-or-queue-custom-functions-using-jquery). Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me for further questions

Comment: NO!! it's a custom made animation!!!!

Comment: ok! second link is right!