# How to wait until some jQuery methods are finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am using Node.js with `cheerio` (a jQuery module on Node.js) and `fetch` (a module to get HTML body like `request`) to get some data from a website and save into MongoDB.

I can select the elements like jQuery in browsers

I have to get some `data` and the pass the `data` to a `callback` function, something like:

```
var data = "";
var fetchById = function(id, callback){
    var data = $("#"+id).parent().siblings(".someClass").text().replace(/\s/g, ""); // line 3
    callback(null, data);
};
```

and then ...

```
fetchById(10987, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        // errorHandle(err);
    }else{
        // db.save(data);
    }
});
```

But sometimes the `callback` is invoked before line 3 has successfully retrieved `data`, therefore, `data` is an empty string `""`

How can I ensure that the `callback` is invoked after line 3 is finished?

Comment: javascript runes linearly, it shouldn't run 'callback' before the 3rd line here finishes, the only exception is asynchronous calls, does not look like the case here.

Comment: I expect you have done so, but we have to be sure... Have you checked that only your `fetchById` function calls taht callback? And that the only call is made by the context you are currently debugging?

Comment: No other call is made in that callback. As mentioned, sometimes I successfully get the data by the jQuery methods, sometimes fail...so I think the only reason is, line 3 needs different length of time on every call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by explicit queueing. See [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

For example (from the API):

```
$( "#foo" ).slideUp();
$( "#foo" ).queue(function() {
  alert( "Animation complete." );
  $( this ).dequeue();
});
```

Which is the same as executing `.slideUp()` first and then, as a callback, executing the `alert()`.

As for you code, this would turn into something like this:

```
var data = 0;

$("#some_element").queue("yourQueue", function() {
  console.log("First");

  // first function
  data = $("#"+id).parent().siblings(".someClass").text().replace(/\s/g, "");

  $(this).dequeue("yourQueue");
});

$("#some_element").queue("yourQueue", function() {
  console.log("Second");

  // second function
  callback(null, data);    // if callback() is a declared function, this should work

  $(this).dequeue("yourQueue");
});

$("#some_element").dequeue("yourQueue");
```

Where I used the code from this answer: [How do I chain or queue custom functions using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095263/how-do-i-chain-or-queue-custom-functions-using-jquery/1095703#1095703)

Important to note here, is that the `.queue()` function must be called on **the same** global element, to make sure the functions are executed (explicitly) sequential.

Comment: The `.queue()` method works for me! but I switch to `jsdom` with jQuery instead of `cheerio` sine it has no  `.queue()` method

Comment: @WhyCode: Well, if you think I answered your question, consider accepting it.